# PHP preg_replace: how to replace text between tags?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a function doit() that transforms text that way:

```
I like berries -> I LikE BerrieS.
```

And I need it to work with html-text to.
How can I transform text only between html tags? Don't touch tag name and all tag attributes. E.g. I need:

```
<p class="super green" style="height: auto">I LikE BerrieS</p>
```

but not:

```
<P ClasS="SupeR GreeN" StylE="HeighT: AutO">I LikE BerrieS</P>
```

I've tried simple preg_replace() patterns, but nothing worked. I'm new to regexp and need help.

May be preg_match() would be better?
Any suggestions? It would be nice to provide working php-code.

Comment: Clear what you want from us?

Comment: It would be nice to provide working php-code.

Comment: What have you tries so far? Pleas edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Somerussian If you are waiting for someone to provide you with a solution that handles nested tags, please update your question with a deliberate sample string that will express your logic, and also post your expected output from your html string with nested tags.  This seems like a job for DomDocument and/or XPath.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = '<div>some other text</div> 
<p class="super green" style="height: auto">i like berries</p>';

//this preg is searching for tags and text inside it
//and then change all first words to upper
$text = preg_replace_callback('#(<.*?>)(.*?)(</.*?>)#', function($matches){

  //this preg is searching for last letters in words and changing it to upper
  $t = preg_replace_callback('#([^ ])( |$)#', function($matches2){
    return strtoupper($matches2[1]) . $matches2[2];
  }, ucwords($matches[2]));
  return $matches[1] . $t . $matches[3];
}, $text);

var_dump($text);
```

Comment: Wow.... giving -1 because of lack of comment even when answer is right... bravo ! Comment added...

Comment: Ok, thx for your explanation. It is strange that people can do here things by anonymous and you even can not discuss 'why?'.

Comment: Great! But it doesn't work with inner tags, e.g:    `<div>some <span class="red">other</span> text</div> <p class="super green" style="height: auto">i like berries</p>`
Could you fix it?

Comment: Here you have tag in tag. You didn't mention that situation. Well... I will try.

Comment: I give up for now. I didn't work with recursive patterns earlier and I need first learn a little about it but now I have to do my job at work.