# PHP preg_replace: how to replace spaces inside html tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace spaces inside a tag to other symbol. For example:

```
<p class="hero big" style="color: inherit; border: none">Super big hero <br />example Yeah</p>
```

to

```
<p~class="hero~big"~style="color:~inherit;~border:~none">Super big hero <br~/>example Yeah</p>
```

I'm new to regexp and don't know to start with. I'm able to replace spaces everywhere, but not inside a tag.

Ho to do it? Could you please provide working php code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: What is your objective, why you want to remove space of tag properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to skip outside tags like this:

```
$str = preg_replace('~>[^<]*(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+~','~', $str);
```

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/575738)

Answer (score 0):

try this, It will replace spaces inside tag with ~

```
<?php
  $data = '<p class="hero big" style="color: inherit; border: none">Super big hero <br />example Yeah</p>';
  $replace = preg_replace('/(<[^>]*)\s+([^<]*>)/', '$1~$2', $data);
  echo $replace;
?>
```

Comment: It changes only the last space inside tag. Could you fix it?  And replace $before with $data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$text = htmlspecialchars('<p class="hero big" style="color: inherit; border: none">Text <br />Text</p>', ENT_QUOTES);

$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', '~', $text);

echo $text;
```

Note:- Treat html tags and main text separately

Comment: Doesn't work - it changes spaces everywhere. Could you fix it?

Comment: told you, you have to add the text like, 'Super big hero' after the conversion. Add it later

Comment: how to do it? Function will get some text and should perform some actions with it. It won't combine something by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [PHP preg_replace: how to replace text between tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385881/php-preg-replace-how-to-replace-text-between-tags), here's a solution:

```
<?php
$s = '<p class="hero big" style="color: inherit; border: none">Super big hero <br />example Yeah</p>';
$text = preg_replace_callback('#(<)([^>]+)(>)#', function($matches){
    return $matches[1].str_replace(" ", "~", $matches[2]).$matches[3];
}, $s);
?>
```

Comment: Do you see these double quotes which will make your code snippet fail?

Comment: Double quotes fixed. Thanks.